# JQuery footable sorting bug(?)

Tags: jquery

[Edit] It is actually a bug as listed [here](https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable/issues/22)

I'm using the footable plugin for responsive and sortable tables. 
But the sorting function is not working as it should.

I put up a test table [here](http://www.vitto.mt.it/app/table.php). As you load the table and click the category header to sort the data by it, as you can see the table does not get sorted.
But if you order by title and 'then' by category it does work.

Comment: Your demo is working and the bug seems to be closed. You should close this question

Comment: for what i've understood i've not enough rep to close a question..is it right?

Comment: You should be able to "delete" your own question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions

Comment: no problem to delete it but could it be useful to keep it alive if anyone has the same problem?